# route to angular page from react page

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

the landing page and all other pages are developed in react, one page developed in angular. How to route to the angular page from the react page or How to configure server config files to handle the request accordingly.
got stuck for the last 2 days, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Both apps are hosted separately. right? if so, can't you just add a hyperlink to the angular page?

Comment: yes I can, but I prefer this way like route to an angular page from react page using react-router. in react-router, on hit of URL we are calling react component, similar to that I want to redirect to an angular page from react on hit of URL. All pages are developed in react except one page that is developed in angular. So trying to route to an angular page from react

Comment: I don't think I understand it. You will be able to open a web page using `window.open(linkToAngular)`.

Comment: If it's not helpful, can you add more details with example.